# How to create hook for altering every node form?

Tags: 7, forms

I tried:

> mymodule_form_node_alter
>
> mymodule_form_node_form_alter

and global hook:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'node-form') {
      #set message
  }
}
```

None from above works for me.

I need to create hook that invokes on every node form. if it possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if (strpos($form_id, '_node_form') !== FALSE) {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Do stuff.
}
```

It could be that it didn't work because you have to clear the cache after adding the hook.

Comment: This is the right way to target node forms in D7..!!

Answer (score 2):

Use `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()` to provide a form-specific alteration for shared forms. For your example this would be:

```
function yourmodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // code that runs on every node form
}
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7

Answer (score 1):

I find better solution:

```
if (isset($form['#node'])) {

}
```

Another solution is to use: [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7)